# Normalization does not solve Fortify error

Tags: java, fortify

Recently we added checking with Fortify to our code during build.
Following there are 2 lines of code, both lines cause 2 critical errors in Fortify: "Path manipulation".
Notice that I added the call to normalize() just to avoid that, and for the same reason I used a Path instead of String.
But now, instead of having 1 error as previously, I have 2 errors (in both lines).

```
Path normalizedPath = Paths.get(aPath + "/" + aStringFromDB + "/" + aFileName + ".txt").normalize();
BufferedOutputStream b = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(String.valueOf(normalizedPath))));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It came out that the "normalize" of Path was not considered by Fortify.
The solution was to import and use the Apache normalize():

```
// import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
String normalizedPath = FilenameUtils.normalize((aPath + "/" + aStringFromDB + "/" + aFileName + ".txt");
BufferedOutputStream b = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(normalizedPath)));
```

Comment: It's also not working, showing Path Violation in Veracode & Sonar

Comment: FilenameUtils.normalize exactly does the intented action but Fortify not recognizes it. So we are suppressing the issue after adding FilenameUtils.normalize.

Comment: I don't have anymore that project, but maybe you can try to use  File.separator instead of (back)slash. It may not work and maybe you already have that; in case, it's anyway a good practice I didn't respect at the time I asked this question.